# Android - Google Maps api v2 - Disable Zoom control

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming

How do I disable the Zoom In button on the Google Map?

I tried looking for commands like:
`map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true)...SOMETHING` but nothing exists.

I want to leave creating my own buttons for zooming as a last resort.

**UPDATE:** I should clarify, I only want to disable the Zoom In button, not the whole Zoom Control.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

the setting you used is right, but to disable it, it should be false.

```
map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
```

hope I got your question right..

**Edit**

Unfortunately, you can't hide one zoom buttons, what you can do is hide both buttons and create your own custom zoom control and place them on the your map.

Comment: Hi @Coderji, thanks for the reply. I should clarify, I want to disable only one button: Zoom In button. Is this possible?

Comment: Ah okay, I was hoping to avoid creating my own, but fair enough, I shall do that. Thank you anyway

Comment: Just to clarify. It remove the zoom button but the user still able to zoom in and out with fingers. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 8):

@Coderji said it's impossible. I say it's possible :-)

You can hide one of zoom button (+ or -) and perform on them all operations like in normal view (margins, size, padding, etc.)

```
    SupportMapFragment mapView = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    View zoomControls = mapView.getView().findViewById(0x1);

    for(int i=0;i<((ViewGroup)zoomControls).getChildCount();i++){
        View child=((ViewGroup)zoomControls).getChildAt(i);
        if (i==0) {
            // there is your "+" button, zoom in

        }
        if (i==1) {
            // there is your "-" button, I hide it in this example
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Call this on your `GoogleMap` to get `UiSettings`
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#getUiSettings()

Then`setZoomControlsEnabled(false)` on the `UiSettings`
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings#setZoomControlsEnabled(boolean)

Comment: Hey @Gabe, as I mentioned in another comment, I want to disable only the Zoom In button, not the whole object/element.

Answer (score 2):

In jetpack compose you can easily set zoomControlsEnabled = false

```
 GoogleMap(uiSettings = 
             MapUiSettings(
                zoomControlsEnabled = false
               )
              ) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can use this code to enable

```
mMap.uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true)
```